How to access a slice with a dynamic value in SystemVerilog?
I want to access a slice with a dynamic value. I have tried to do it in different ways.  In the first case reducing the logic of the module for the control of the index value etc, verilator told me that it is not a constant value and I agree with that and then I change for the second version but I got the same result.
1:
module m1 (
input  logic [4:0] in1,  // 8-bit input vector 1
input  logic [4:0] in2,  // 8-bit index
output logic [4:0] out   // 8-bit output vector
);
logic add;

always_comb begin
add = (in2[in1[4:0]-1] & (in2[(in1[4:0]-2):0] != '0); //summary rounding
end

out = in1 + add;//summary of the final operation
endmodule

2:
module m1 (
input  logic [4:0] in1,  // 8-bit input vector 1
input  logic [4:0] in2,  // 8-bit index
output logic [4:0] out   // 8-bit output vector
);
logic add;

always_comb begin
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin
if((in1[4:0]-2) == i)begin
add = (in2[in1[4:0]-1] & (in2[(i:0] != '0); //summary rounding
end
end

out = in1 + add;//summary of the final operation
endmodule

The logic I am trying to implement is the rounding mode of riscv-v 1.0.
I have tried several tests trying to do static logic but I can't find a way to solve the problem. How can I implement this logic in hardware.

Good afternoon,
The final solution that I found is the next one:
prev_shift = '0;
prev_shift = in2 << (in1[range in2] - 2);
not_zero = prev_shift != 0;

Thank @Suhas for the help

If you are trying to implement the rne mode, you seem to be missing a bit of logic. According to the RVV-v1.0 spec, to perform rne you need to calculate the rounding increment by using the following logic -> v[d-1] & (v[d-2:0]!= 0 | v[d]).
Also, isn't in1 you input vector. You are trying to index in2 which is your index with your in1 which is your actual vector to be indexed. You also do not have to specify the width of your logic (like in in1[in2[4:0]-1]) it can be described as in1[in2-1].
To achieve what you are trying to do, using functions can be quite useful so I would suggest taking a look at functions in SV.

Thanks for your help I am going to check the SV function, the problem I am fighting is with (v[d-2:0]!= 0) because d comes in the value of another logical vector. So I have to take a dynamic slices of a vector that depends on a value of another vector. Then I can't compile to build that hardware as it is not a constant value

Have you considered adding a reg or a logic to store the slice?

@Juan_R I think this should help you -> https://github.com/pulp-platform/ara/blob/main/hardware/src/lane/fixed_p_rounding.sv#L54

In a logic, but I think I can manage with the link you shared with me. Thank you
